# How to return value from Inlet

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I am new to Akka Streams and looking at the following graph two question come up:

https://gist.github.com/rocketpages/9ee1523db698edc4cfb5#file-flightdelays-scala

1. I am wondering how would I pass the value of Inlet G to the caller of a function containing the graph definition for further processing e.g. returning an http-response?
2. How would I combine the values from both Inlets E & G and return the composite to the caller of a function containing the grap definition for further processing e.g. returning an http-response?